# Display Rectangle outside of parent or Window

Tags: qt, qml, popupwindow

Wanna to show menu or [`Combobox`](https://forum.qt.io/topic/88137/qml-combobox-dropdown-outside-parent) or [`Popup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#details) over out of parent. I tried [document overlay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html#:%7E:text=Overlay%20provides%20a%20layer%20for,a%20popup%20in%20scene%20coordinates.) but it did not work, like below image when right clicked in any software. Notice that I don't want to use two [`Window`s](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#details)!.

[image]

Comment: The only way is to use two Windows though.

Comment: I want my main `Window` has to title bar but other panel has not to use title bar!

Comment: With `flags` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum. solved. Hint: https://forum.qt.io/topic/92281/how-to-add-additional-controls-to-window-title-bar/6